# C# return method running twice, though only called once

Tags: c#, methods, return

I have this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ReturnRandomNumber();
            Console.WriteLine("The number returned by ReturnRandomNumber was: " + ReturnRandomNumber());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static int ReturnRandomNumber()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This string should only be displayed once, since the method is only called once...");
            Random random = new Random();
            int numberToReturn = random.Next(1, 100);
            Console.WriteLine("So should this string...");

            return numberToReturn;
        }
    }
}
```

The console output when I run the program is:

```
This string should only be displayed once, since the method is only called once...
So should this string...
This string should only be displayed once, since the method is only called once...
So should this string...
The number returned by ReturnRandomNumber was: [some random number between 1-100]
```

I only call ReturnRandomNumber() once from my main method, so why is it apparently run twice?

If I make ReturnRandomNumber a void, and comment out the return line, as well as the WriteLine in Main, the method is only run once, so the double run must have something to do with the return - I just can't figure out what?!

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are calling the method twice man, one the first line and then in the console write.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to figure out how to work with return methods, but obviously I haven't gotten it right yet. I thought that I was only putting the returned value in the Console.WriteLine, but now I realize I'm actually calling the function. Is there a way to get the returned value from a method without calling the method?

Comment: @TorBrandt It is like shopping: It is not enough to pay for the goods, you have to carry them home ;o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling the method twice.  Once in the first line of main:

```
ReturnRandomNumber();
```

The second time in your writeline statement:

```
Console.WriteLine("The number returned by ReturnRandomNumber was: " + ReturnRandomNumber());
```

If you only want to call the method once, and keep the value for displaying later, you should do something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     int number = ReturnRandomNumber();
     Console.WriteLine("The number returned by ReturnRandomNumber was: " + number);
     Console.ReadKey();
}
```

return in a method just means it returns the value.  If you want use the value returned, you need to keep it for later - so store the result in a variable.

You already do this with out realizing it when using Random.Next(1,100).  Random is a class, and Next is a method on that class that returns a value.

Comment: @TorBrandt You should accept the answer if it is the right one.

Comment: @Sir Rufo I thought there was such a feature, but I couldn't find it. I marked the green check mark, is that it?